# UIView width shows differently at first start

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, attributes, uisearchbar

I have a UIView which has below attributes. A SearchController is adding inside this view programmatically. However, problem in GIF occurs.

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchView: UIView!
 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setup the Search Controller
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

[image: GIF]
[image: Attributes]

Comment: Please post your searchController creation code.

Comment: how it is possible that "SearchController is adding … view programmatically", but you are showing poperies from interface builder (IB)? Show the code and describe how it is connected to IB.

Comment: I added the code. I'm creating UIView in storyboard and searchcontroller in code. Then add searchcontroller as subview of UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Its pleasant to here from you i will modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

move your adding search bar code to

> viewDidAppear

Your view will not get proper device frame if auto layout is enabled in viewDidLoad